# Bibliography format transformation

Tags: bibliographies

According to the template of Springer the bibliography should be as followed:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
    \bibitem{RefJ}
    % Format for Journal Reference
    Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
    % Format for books
    \bibitem{RefB}
    Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
\end{thebibliography}
```

I have already had a `bib` file that contains the following:

```
@article{kargupta2004fourier,
  title={A fourier spectrum-based approach to represent decision trees for mining data streams in mobile environments},
  author={Kargupta, Hillol and Park, Byung-Hoon},
  journal={Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={16},
  number={2},
  pages={216--229},
  year={2004},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

    @article{mukherjee2006privacy,
      title={A privacy-preserving technique for Euclidean distance-based mining algorithms using Fourier-related transforms},
      author={Mukherjee, Shibnath and Chen, Zhiyuan and Gangopadhyay, Aryya},
      journal={The VLDB Journal—The International Journal on Very Large Data Bases},
      volume={15},
      number={4},
      pages={293--315},
      year={2006},
      publisher={Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.}
    }
    @article{freund1997decision,
      title={A decision-theoretic generalization of on-line learning and an application to boosting},
      author={Freund, Yoav and Schapire, Robert E},
      journal={Journal of computer and system sciences},
      volume={55},
      number={1},
      pages={119--139},
      year={1997},
      publisher={Elsevier}
    }
```

and the code in my `.TEX` file is as followed:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \newpage
    \bibliography{BibliographyFinal}
    \bibliographystyle{apa}
```

How can I transform it in order to meet the demanded format of bibliography?

Comment: I would ask first, if submitting a bib-file is ok, Springer provides own `bst` files which should be perfect. If so, the `bbl` generated by BibTeX contains the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, Can you please explain? It means that I can use my bibliography in the format as it is now with no need to change or transform it?

Comment: @Avi Your `.bib` file just contains the information about the entries. It's a database, not a format.  The `.bst` file (in the case of `bibtex`) does the formatting of the entries using the data in the `.bib` file.  So you should never need to do anything to your `.bib` file other than make sure the required fields are present and the data is accurate.  Then you can use any `.bst` file you like.

Comment: Thanks again. My only question is that it seem as if Springer asks to insert the bib file into the content of the .TEX file. Am I wrong?

Comment: The most reliable source that answers this question are the editors from Springer (or somebody authorative there).

Comment: Thanks a lot. As seen there the relevant instructions are for Non-BibTeX users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bib` file can be used. In addition the style should be defined according to Springer `bst` file.
It can be done after copying the relevant `.bst` file to the directory and using:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \newpage
    \bibliography{BibliographyFinal}
    \bibliographystyle{spbasic}
```

Where `spbasic` is the chosen `.bst` style.